Circuit Breaker rating vs Stove
The datasheet for this Bosch 800 series stove calls for a "50 amp circuit breaker". My current stove is on a 50amp circuit in my house (Washington state). Could I replace my current stove with this new one?
I remember reading that you should de-rate breakers by 0.8 which is what is giving me pause. I was not sure if I can match the amperage rating of the appliance to be 100% of the circuit rating.

Ranges follow their own rules
Ranges (stoves) don't follow normal derating rules; instead, they are governed by the rules in NEC Table 220.55 and its Notes.  So, go right ahead and put in your new range, as an 8400W range load is no challenge for a 50A circuit.

Plus the manufacturer says to do it, and the stove is thus UL listed for that.
